# how to insert image in database using ajax in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

> i am trying to add an image to my database using Javascript and ajax 
>   and my code works very well without inserting the image in the database but when i try to insert the image the code is not working at all so here
>   is my code
>
> 1. register.php

```
    <form id="registrationForm">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" required>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required>
        <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="mail" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        <input type="file" class="input" id="profileimg" name="profileimg" placeholder="Profile image">
        <input type="text" class="input" minlength="11" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Mobile " required>
         <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit btn-Blue" value="Register">
        </form>
        <script>
        var submit_button = $(".btnSubmit"); 
        $(submit_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fname = $( "#firstname" ).val();
        var lname = $( "#lastname" ).val();
        var mail = $( "#mail" ).val();
        var tel = $( "#tel" ).val();
        var aFormData = new FormData();
        aFormData.append("profileimg", $('#profileimg')[0].files[0]); 
        jQuery.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type : 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
        action : 'trip_register_ajax',
        'f_name': fname ,
        'l_name': lname ,
        'e-mail': mail  ,
        'mob': tel    ,
        'profile' : aFormData 
        },
        success : function( response ) {
        alert(response)
                }
              }); 
                       });
</script>
```

> and here is my functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_trip_register_ajax', 'trip_register_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_trip_register_ajax', 'trip_register_ajax' );
function trip_register_ajax() {
    $firstname=$_POST['f_name'];
$lastname=$_POST['l_name'];
$mail=$_POST['e-mail'];
$tel=$_POST['mob'];
$upload_image=$_FILES['profileimg'];
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('wp_users' , array(
                                   'first_name'       => $firstname,
                                   'last_name'   => $lastname,
                                   'user_email'    => $mail,
                                   'tel'   => $tel, 
                                  'image'   => $upload_image, 
                                   ));
                               }
```

Comment: I think you have to store images in a database as a blob type. but it is recommended to just store the url and save the photos in the wpupload folder .

Comment: thank you very much..it works fine now :)